# Using snap svg for manipulating/dragging/hide/show nodes in SVG diagrams

Tags: svg, d3.js, snap.svg

I have a Network Diagram(Nodes and Edges) in SVG generated by GraphViz tool. I want to make the diagram interactive in the sense, it should be draggable, on click of a node some other nodes to be hidden.ETC. Can any one suggest snapSVG is sufficient for that? I cannot add any thing to the SVG diagram that is my restriction. How can we make existing svg diagrams forced directed? Any help, starting point, fiddle will be helpful. I have hands on in d3.js is it achievable by d3.js?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible, maybe be aware Snap.svg isn't so compatible with older browsers (in which case you could look at Raphael which is Snaps older brother, d3 is very well established as well). They all have all the basics, handlers, animation etc. However, although its possible, it may well be quite a lot of work (so may want to stick with what you know).

You may want to look into whether you want to autocreate connecting elements and move automatically, or are happy moving endpoints manually.

It may also depend on things like what you want to happen after dragging the elements. Do you want to save them ? Some of that may be quite important as to how you approach it, maybe more important than dragging as most will support that.

Comment: My svg diagram is already created, I need to select them and provide required properties. My idea is to make the svg a forced directed graph as made by d3.js. Is there any generic way to make an SVG tobe force directed.

Comment: Not sure of a generic way, but my gut instinct would be to stick with d3, as there is some of that built in, and more examples of force direct to reference, as opposed to snap.

Comment: d3 has the specific layouts like force directed, but you made need to do some translation from your already created data to that setup. The force-direction of the layout changes translations, orientations, etc of the elements based on it's dynamic algorithm. A pre-created diagram has the all rather "locked down".